# Redundant code between bundles

Tags: php, symfony, refactoring

I have an symfony 2 appliction who consume cloud API. These APIs share the same logic, only the methods called are differents.

How can I organize mo code  ?

- One bundle per API  ? Actually I tried this way but each provider needs more and more redundant code.
- a single bundle with switch/case for the APIs
- one routing to a controller with a reference to the API provider and after call a  ???  Service  ?  Sub controller  ?
- other idea ?

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question at all. But for my experience I recommend the use of one Bundle with multiple services. Create a one common classes and interfaces and reuse the code, create class for each API but use interfaces to simplify the way to access to each one.

Example:

```
interface timeAPIInterface
{
    public function giveMeTheTime();
}

class timeInChina implements timeAPIInterface
{
    public function giveMeTheTime()
    {
        //logic to connect to CHINA API and get the time
    }
}

class timeInUSA implements timeAPIInterface
{
    public function giveMeTheTime()
    {
        //logic to connect to USA API and get the time
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you can implements something like:

```
$service = $request->get('time_service');
$time = $this->get($service)->giveMeTheTime();
```

The url can look like: /time/api?time_service=china_time

This is a very basic example of the use of interfaces to simplify the way to access to classes sharing the same behavior. Using the same logic can improve your controller to access to multiple service using only one controller and bundle.